# Using input to assign a name in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am constructing a list for my Shiny app. I want to fill the list by name (since I'm filling the list with more lists) using an input, sort of like this:

```
     a <- list()
     b <- list() 
     a$input$select1 <- b
```

Does anyone know how to do this? When I call names(a) I get input.

Comment: Use `a[[input$select1]]`. You can't use variables after the `$` operator.

Comment: Hey, it worked. Now that I see it, it's obvious. Thank you so much.